# Why do the Japanese use loanwords for words that have functional equivalents?

Tags: word-choice, loanwords

It strikes me, reading Japanese that katakana is often used for words that have functional equivalents in the Japanese language. Why is this?
For instance, using ビル as opposed to 建物。

Or ブルー instead of 青い.

Or ジュース.　Am I supposed to believe the Japanese never smashed fruit to drink the liquid before they "met the west"?

Most other languages are not so accommodating.

Comment: Interesting question, but please provide examples.

Comment: There's also ビデオ and 動画, which is one of my favorite examples since I've *still* never been formally taught 動画.

Comment: For reference, there's also 果汁【かじゅう】.

Comment: To be completely honest, I do NOT understand this question.  The number of katakana words we actively use even though we already have "functional equivalents" for them is very  marginal compared with the tens of thousands of Sino loanwords we use instead of the originally Japanese words.  Yet the question is almost always "Why use so many katakana words?"  You yourself used many originally non-English words to ask this question as well.  How do you explain that?

Comment: Non-English words? You mean non-English in origin right? Because they appear in use in the English language much the same way as they do in their origin language. Besides that and English being an almost completely borrowed language it is not hard to see why. But I digress

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my expererience and from some research I did for an essay back in University,
this stems as a large part of the "Westernisation" of Japanese words in the lead up to
and immediately following the 1964 Tokyo Olympics in preparation for the influx of
foreigners that were expected as well as a slight difference in meanings. JR  (Then JNR) changed all it's stations sign to also
include a romaji reading during this period. It became "fashionable" to have the
name of a shop etc. to feature a "modern", foreign-sounding name as the Showa era
went on, leading to a peak in about the early 80s. There has been a lot of complaints
directed at NHK, especially for Katakana-ising words which have functional equivalents
leading to many elderly people unable to understand some broadcasts. Further, it
appears as though at least the words you mention, differ slightly in meaning between
their origin language (the katakana part) and the Japanese use (the kanji) as below.

For example.

- 建物 means any built, freestanding structure (Tokyo Tower, Roppongi Hills Apartments, a random office block in Nihonbashi, Tokyo Sky Tree)
- ビル means specificallybuilding (In which case Tokyo Tower and the Sky Tree would not be included whereas Roppongi Hills Apartments, a random office block in Nihonbashi would be)

---

- 青い the Japanese 青い is a kind of aqua colour (the Japanese traffic light "green" equivalent)
- ブルー blue in this instance would be akin to something like rgb(0,0,255) / a solid blue colour

---

- 果汁 fruit juice
- ジュース can mean fruit juice, carbonated drinks like coca cola and other like drinks etc.

Comment: Do you have a living example of Coke being referred as ジュース?Carbonated drinks are usually called ソフトドリンク.

Comment: @Rilakkuma AFAIK ソフトドリンク is a relatively new word in Japanese. Young people tend to use ソフトドリンク a lot (they learn at school that *juice* means 果汁 in English). Elder people, say over 60, may not even understand ソフトドリンク, and use ジュース for any kind of beverage except tea and alcohol.

Comment: By living example you mean a link of some description? I did say CAN MEAN as when I was in High School, University and now my Job, either my classmates or coworkers have referred to it as such. Even when I protest saying, "Isn't Juice only from fruit?" I get a nonchalant "It is probably 和製英語". My 24yo coworker just commented "日本人適当に「ジュース」を言う" so it doesn't seem limited to the older generation. I think of juice as juice and carbonated drinks as carbonated drinks. As to @naruto's comment, I did mention the older generation not being Katakana-go literate so I agree with your point.

Comment: You can say one living example is me, who spent the first 12 years of my life believing ジュース refers to any sugary beverage :)

Comment: @naruto : I knew it couldn't have just been the people around me. Is the scope just limited to sugary drinks? Would Soda Water be ジュース or just ソーダ？

Comment: Younger people today will definitely say "No it's not ジュース", but my grandmother might have said yes.